# Why lsblk command not showing /boot partition?

Tags: linux, boot

**I tried to find boot partition on my system and executed lsblk command**

```
sda              8:0    0 930.4G  0 disk
├─sda1           8:1    0     1G  0 part
├─sda2           8:2    0    40G  0 part
├─sda3           8:3    0 763.6G  0 part
└─sda4           8:4    0 125.8G  0 part
sde              8:64   0   100G  0 disk
├─sde1           8:65   0     2G  0 part
└─sde2           8:66   0    98G  0 part
 ├─sles-root0 254:0    0  27.9G  0 lvm  /
 └─sles-root  254:1    0    70G  0 lvm
```

**But when I did df -h /boot, this is showing**

```
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/sles-root0   28G  3.8G   23G  15% /
```

What does this means and how to confirm and the system has boot partition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A boot partition is necessary if your system firmware has some limitations that prevent it from accessing the full size of the disk. Creating a separate partition for `/boot` at the beginning of the disk ensures that the things the bootloader needs to access (using the drivers built into the firmware) will always be located within the firmware-accessible area of the disk.

Once the bootloader has successfully loaded the kernel and the initramfs file, the kernel will start up and begin using its own drivers, which are easier to update than the system firmware, and so are much less likely to have restrictive disk size limitations.

If your system firmware has no such limitations, nothing stops you from creating `/boot` as a regular directory within your root filesystem. As long as the bootloader can read that filesystem type (and that filesystem is fully contained within the disk the bootloader is reading), it will work just fine.

Another possible reason for having a boot partition is if you have an encrypted root filesystem, and your bootloader does not support the encryption. In that situation, the only way the bootloader can do its job is to have the kernel and initramfs files in an unencrypted partition. In such setups, the tools and configuration required to get the necessary passphrase or key from the user and unlock the encryption will need to be be included in initramfs.

Even if you do have a `/boot` partition, it does not have to be continuously mounted. It only needs to be mounted when you are either a) installing a kernel update, b) updating your initramfs file or c) updating your bootloader or its configuration. Some distributions leave a `/boot` partition unmounted in normal use, and their kernel/initramfs/bootloader update tools include a feature that will mount and unmount `/boot` as necessary.

Regarding your `df -h /boot` output:

```
Filesystem              Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/sles-root0   28G  3.8G   23G  15% /
```

Since you specified `/boot` as a parameter for the `df` command, the command will show only the filesystem that contains the specified file or directory. Since the `Mounted on` column says `/`, it is the root filesystem.

The next step is to run `ls -l /boot`: if the directory contains files named like `vmlinuz-<kernel version number>`, `System.map-<kernel version number>`, then the kernel, initramfs (if needed) and the bootloader configuration (if applicable) are stored in directory `/boot` on the root filesystem, and there is no separate `/boot` filesystem in your current configuration.

But if the `ls -l /boot` indicates the directory is completely empty, then it would suggest the real `/boot` filesystem is currently unmounted, and this empty directory is just a (currently-unused) mount point for it.

---

Verifying that your current configuration is quite easy if you have a modern UEFI system (and are not using the legacy BIOS compatibility boot). Start by running `efibootmgr -v` as root: it will display the current firmware boot settings. The UEFI boot entries will include a boot path string, which can have various forms, but the most common form for booting Linux is:

```
HD(1,GPT,<PARTUUID string for ESP containing the bootloader file>,0x800,0x82000)/File(<bootloader pathname within the ESP partition>)
```

With `lsblk -o +PARTUUID, you will be able to view the partition identifiers of each partition on your system, and so find the ESP (EFI System Partition) that will contain the bootloader *as a regular file*. The ESP is very often a FAT32 partition, as all versions of the UEFI specification have always required that all UEFI firmware implementations must understand FAT32, but firmware developers are allowed to add support for other filesystems too.

The bootloader pathname is typically written using Windows pathname conventions, using backslashes as directory separators. So if the bootloader path displayed by `efibootmgr -v` is e.g. `\EFI\SLES\GRUBX64.EFI`, then if you mount the ESP at `/boot/efi`, you should find the bootloader at `/boot/efi/EFI/SLES/grubx64.efi` (FAT32 is case insensitive, and the UEFI firmware should be too... however, there may be bugs in some UEFI implementations).

The `efibootmgr -v` also includes the `BootCurrent:` line that identifies the four-digit number of the boot entry that was used to boot the currently running system.

Comment: This explanation clears all my doubt, just a small doubt I have is if system don't have /boot partition, it means all the necessary info needed to load kernel , OS resides on /root partition?

Comment: *Usually* but not necessarily *always*, yes. The firmware (BIOS or UEFI) will set the requirements of where the bootloader must be and what form it must take; then there must be some small piece of information wherever the bootloader can find it, to tell where to begin looking for the rest of the boot configuration. For example, if you needed to hide the existence of a second OS on a laptop, you might place its bootloader and *the necessary info* on a USB stick. Without the stick, the system runs Windows and there's a "recovery image" partition on the disk. With the stick... something else.

Answer (score 1):

A boot partition isn't mandatory. Not every system has one, and the output of your commands implies that yours doesn't.

Comment: The output which is shown under df -h /boot command ,what that means?

Comment: @GauravBaghel Try doing `df -h` on a few directories that you know for sure aren't partitions, and look at the output you get from that.

Comment: I did and all etc ,home etc directories are mounted on root directory ,so if there is not boot path found ,then what will happen, OS will not boot ,right?

Comment: @GauravBaghel Didn't we just establish that you don't have a boot partition, but that your OS boots fine anyway?

Comment: But some where boot info should be there?

Comment: @GauravBaghel You do have a /boot directory, and the boot info is there. I fail to see the confusion.

Comment: So df -h /boot is a confirmation that there is  a boot path which is mounted on root only,right?

Comment: No. The `/boot` directory is part of your root (`/`) filesystem. There is nothing extra to mount on `/boot` unless that directory is currently empty